# Java Pattern for Word without Spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am wondering what the regex for a word would be, I can seem to find it anywhere? The string I\m trying to match "Loop-num + 5" and I want to extract the "Loop-num" part. I am unsure what the regex would be to do so.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(loop-.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("5 * loop-num + 5");
if(matcher.find()){
    String extractedString = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(extractedString);
}
```

From this I get: "loop-num + 5"

Comment: Please Post what you have already tried so far .. give us some code :)

Comment: @Kami Sorry, but I have added what I have tried now.

Comment: You want the numbers or you want the  "loop-num" String to be extracted ?

Comment: might be sth like this `loop*-\w{1,3}` or `l\w{3}-\w{3}` or `l\w{3}-n\w{2}` depents what you exactly want in general. Those expressions are naive but you need to describe more what you want to exctract from string.

Comment: @Kami I want the loop-num to be extracted

Comment: You could also be a little bit more specific with the pattern and do something like this [A-Za-z]\w+\-[A-Za-z]\w+ that pattern will look for two words with a dash between them.

Comment: @ThePrimedTNT then just use the pattern `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("loop-num");`

Comment: Also take a look at this site http://www.regexr.com/ it is really good for trying out and testing regex patterns.

Comment: @samuel Thats part of what I needed! just made a few tweaks to it and it worked! Regex: loop-[A-Za-z]\\w+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really plan to use the regex to match words (entities comprising just letters, optionally split with hyphen(s)), you need to consider the following regex:

```
\b\pL+(?:-\pL+)*\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY4gZ6/1)

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\pL+` - 1 or more Unicode letters
- `(?:-\pL+)*` - zero or more sequences of...

  - `-` - a literal hyphen
  - `\pL+` - 1 or more Unicode letters
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

In [Java](http://ideone.com/Iy2cru):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\pL+(?:-\\pL+)*\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("5 * loop-num + 5");
if(matcher.find()){
    String extractedString = matcher.group(0);
    System.out.println(extractedString);
}
```

**Note**: in case words may include digits (not at the starting positions), you can use [`\b\pL\w*(?:-\pL\w*)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/qJ8sQ2/1) with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`. Here, `\w` will match letters, digits and an underscore.